# Asynchronous pipeline in Gitlab for macos notarization

Tags: macos, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, notarize

I use GitLab and I have a 2GB project that needs to be notarized by Apple. Here is the current pipeline flow:

> Compile ==> Test ==> Zip ==> **Notarize** ==> Create Installer ==> Done

The notarization step takes **one hour**. The Apple servers have a queue, so 80% of the time the process actually does nothing. It opens a connection and idles until the upload can happen. So the process does pretty much nothing for a long time.

So the runner is blocked by this task. Can I mark a task as "async" so another task can be executed by this runner? Technically 100 builds could be notarized simultaneously, without any performance issues. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that feature directly available in pipelines.
There is only [gitlab-org/gitlab/issue 27165](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/27165) which might not be 100% a good fit:

> Sometimes it may be necessary to complete a job without affecting the result of the current pipeline.
>
> The simplest example is coverage tests.
>   Now we have to wait for the execution of the coverage tests, although they are performed for a long time, and we only need to perform the usual tests.

It does reference though [gitlab-org/gitlab-foss issue 47063](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/47063#note_165729504) about Out-of-sequence job execution using directed acyclic graphs.

> For example, when a project generates both Android and iOS apps in a multi-stage pipeline, people want the iOS deployment to start as soon as all the iOS tests pass rather than waiting for all the Android tests to pass too.
>   The total compute time might be the same, but the wall-clock time is different.
>
> In more complicated cases, it's possible to significantly reduce the overall wall-clock time of the pipeline by declaring exactly which jobs depend on which other jobs.
>
> A solution like DAG can allow pipelines to be mapped in terms of dependencies, and then cloud compute resources applied automatically in the most efficient way in order to execute. This is very powerful and solves much manual optimization when it comes to pipelines.

This is in GitLab 12.2 and more (Apr. 2019)